Convergence rate of a special series
Consider a convex and non-increasing function $\varphi$, such that
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\varphi(n)e^{n}\leq \infty,   ~\ ~\ ~\  ~\  0\leq \varphi(n)\leq 1$$
What is convergence rate of $\varphi(n)e^{n}$?

@Gary, what about $\phi(n)=e^{-2n}$?

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

@Gary，we want to  show $\varphi(n)  <  \frac{e^{-n}}{n}$, but we have no idea.

If $\phi(n)$ behaves like $ \frac {e^{-n}}{n}$ the sum will diverge, as the sum of $\frac{1}{n}$ diverges.

@Peter，yes, but we can't get $\varphi(n) < \frac{e^{-n}}{n}$ point by point .(Or there exists some N, when $n \geq N, \varphi(n) < \frac{e^{-n}}{n}$,)

What you can say is that $\varphi(n){e^{n}}\to0$ faster than $\frac{1}{n}$, or  $\varphi(n){e^{n}}=o(\frac{1}{n})$. This is little o, not big O.

@Peter  Yes,you are right.I had trouble phrasing it. Thank you!
